# How to add multiple latitude and longitude to URL which can show multiple markers as well?

Tags: java

How to add multiple latitude and longitude to URL which can show multiple markers as well ?

====http://maps.google.com/maps?q=14.6818877,77.6005911

In the above url only one latitude and longitude is placed .i want to add more lat lng. so that while opening url it shows all the latitude and longitude locations pointing with cursors.iam using java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is not a programming question, and is thus off-topic for this site.

Comment: As iam using this in my java code .i thought its a rogramming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=512x512&maptype=roadmap\
&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7C14.6818877,77.6005911%7C15.8281257,78.0372792%7C15.3959840,77.8727193

by adding with %7C ang lat lan we can add multiple cursors.
by using human readable address like this (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?new+york,US) we can get only 15 markers.while using lat lag we can get more cursors